# How to use MonkeyRunner and Robotium together (not separately!)

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-testing, monkeyrunner

How to use MonkeyRunner and Robotium together (not separately!) for testing my Android app

Comment: The question is too generic, do you have an example on how both should work together?

Comment: Robotium and monkeyrunner have nothing much to do with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found this

http://download.yandex.ru/company/experience/yac2012/kharitonenko_yac_2012.pdf

slide #22. There is a scheme, how to use a combination of Robotium and Monkeyrunner.
For example, when in your tests, you need to take a snapshot from Android native Camera, and Robotium can't do that. Monkeyrunner can do it. But most of your test case developed in Robotium, so as I understood, you can run monkeyrunner script for this action, and then continue with Robotium. Am I right?

Comment: Hey, guys! Has anybody tried method of testing Robotium+Monkeyrunner as shown in slide #22 in the link?

Answer (score 1):

In general MonkeyRunner is based on a generic build-in android instrumentation, based on user inputs. It does not require any code knowledge and does not yield any access to the application process.

Whereas Robotium or Espresso is based on the GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner, which runs within the same process like your app, hence allows direct access to view components but does also require code access.

So in general you could do most of the monkey-runner input actions with Robotium / Espresso, but what you can't is to use monkey-runner from within a Robotium test, this is prevented by 
Androids security mechanisms.

Another approach would be running monkey-runner instrumentation's along with Robotium tests in a scripted environment, where monkey-runner is switching between processes, and at a certain time executing the needed Robotium test, but this kind of concept could be very unstable.

An alternative to both are [UI Automator Tests](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html). They provide the benefits of Robotium - Access to the View Hierarchy - and the flexibility of Monkey Runner - using arbitrary input commands -,  but does not require any code knowledge.

Comment: Yeah. but UI Automator available only for API 16+

Comment: True, but most of the relevant devices are working on +16 APIs: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @joecks I guess robotium can work without code access, the blackbox testing tutorials shows something similar.